# Any way to speed up Matlab code that has to search through 20000+ rows for a string 16x?

Tags: string, matlab, search

Basically the way the code works is that the user types in a string (in my case a timestamp like 7:29:29 AM - 2:33:33 PM) and the code reads in a data file from excel that has those strings in it and all the data:
    filename = get(handles.File,'String');
    [Data,Text] = xlsread(filename,2);

```
IndexStart=strmatch(get(handles.StartTime,'String'),Text,'exact'); %start time
IndexEnd=strmatch(get(handles.EndTime,'String'),Text,'exact'); %end time

seconds = IndexEnd-IndexStart;
PlotData = Data([IndexStart: IndexEnd],:);
```

It then searches for the row number of that time stamp in Text and copies the corresponding data section from the data for this time range so that I can plot it. This data is collected for 8+ hours at 1 sample/sec so there are easily 30000 rows in the excel file to search through. This large chunk of data is going to be plotted with labels on the plot for different events (assuming they put an event for every box but i take that into account with the if statement). The way I have this set up now is in a gui where the user places in timestamp values as strings and the code searches for them:

```
if isempty(get(handles.Task16End,'String')) 
IndexTextTask16End  = IndexStart;
else
IndexTextTask16End=strmatch(get(handles.Task16End,'String'),Text,'exact'); %row location for timestamp
end
Task16Span=IndexTextTask16End-IndexTextTask15End; %timespan of this event
Task16LineLocation=Task15LineLocation+ Task16Span/3600; %location for vertical line on graph
```

So i have up to 16 tasks that can be inputted which means that the program has to search through EVERY single available cell in a matlab matrix for these strings until it runs through the code. How can I do this more efficiently? maybe set it to search until it finds a truly empty cell? That would at least limit my search to the given data instead of the entire array possible.

Comment: `strmatch` is not recommend, use `strcmp` here. Or convert using `datenum` and don't look for strings at all.

Comment: strcmp never seems to work for me. it just gives me a bunch of zeroes how do i write that so it gives me the same answer as strmatch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strcmp` is often much faster than `strmatch`; I tried it out and it was much faster on my system, don't know exactly why (like 1000x faster, I wasn't expecting that much difference).

It returns slightly different information - `strcmp` returns a logical array with 1 wherever there's a match - so to get the same output as with `strmatch` just wrap it with a `find`:

```
IndexStart=find(strcmp(get(handles.StartTime,'String'),Text)); %start time
```

Comment: I will give that a try too on the profiler. From what Dang Khoa posted I am trying this right now:     `IndexStart= find(TextConvert==datenum(get(handles.StartTime,'String')))`

Comment: so i tried both formats, mine and yours, and it was still painfully slow. 5min to get a graph with no labels (as in i left the gui blocks empty). is this the best I can get? it was maybe 20sec faster than what I had before this post.

Comment: so i ran the profiler and found my actual culprit. I had a smoothing function that is taking 117 seconds with 49226 calls: `Smooth=smooth(GraphTime, Data(:,1),800,'lowess'); %smoothing function line` anything I can do about that? `GraphTime = [0:grapthtick:totalhours];`

Comment: Why are you calling it so many times? That seems weird. Anyway, since that's totally separate, you should probably post a new question - but you'll need to give more info about where/when that line is called.

Answer (score 1):

If you're reading an Excel spreadsheet for start/end times and doing all this other work in MATLAB, consider converting the times to to their [`datenum` representation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html?refresh=true) after your `xlsread`. This way you can compare numbers, not strings - much faster. Given this, you could use [logical indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/) to build your desired data:

```
times   = datenum(Text); % assumed Text is just a cell array of times
t_start = datenum(get(handles.StartTime,'String'));
t_end   = datenum(get(handles.EndTime, 'String'));

plotData = Data(times >= t_start & times <= t_end); % note the single &, which is different than &&
```

Comment: I can't run datenum on my text data. I get the error failed to lookup month of year. it says that text is a cell array not double but datenum still fails

Comment: @excelhelp Depending on how your times are formatted, you may need to specify a format yourself. See the linked documentatio for `datenum`. For what it's worth, I just ran `datenum({'1:23:45 PM' '1:23:46 PM'})` and it worked. If you still can't figure it out, please edit your question to show what a sample time string might look like.

Comment: I think i figured out why it isn't working. 1) did not know I could specify format, and 2) I have the word 'Time' as a header in the text data array. So the datenum crashes at that first cell every time basically. going to tell it to delete the first row upon finishing xlsread and see if that works. Once I move from strings to nums, how do i alter my search so that it functions the same? basically I am still going to have the user input strings for time, then convert them in the background with datenum, but how do i do a datenummatch function like i do with strmatch now?

Comment: @excelhelp Please refer to my answer. You can just use logical indexing to directly pull the data corresponding to the times you want.